# Do I have access to a counter variable inside .Aggregate?

Tags: c#, string, list, aggregate

I'm using `.Aggregate` on a `List<String>` to concatenate each item. I need to find out when the iteration has hit the last item. I was considering testing `listOfStrings.Last() == currentString` but the last item in the list *could* equal any other if the value is the same.

Comment: For a bit more context - what I want to do is actually concatenate the last item in a different way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you need to know this?

I'm just guessing, but it sounds like you're doing something similar to generating a string such as "x, y, z" and you don't want a comma after the last item.

If this is the case, you can use [`string.Join(separator, items)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992421) instead. Unless you want something which fits the form of "x, y & z"?

If you really need to use `Aggregate`, you can close over an external variable, like:

```
int count = 0;

var aggregated = items.Aggregate(new StringBuilder(), (acc, item) =>
{
    if (++count == items.Count)
    {
        // it's the last item
        acc.Append("last");
    }
    else
    {
        acc.Append("not last, ");
    }
    return acc;
}).ToString();
```

Comment: This aggregate method has already been used, I need to stick with this.  String.Join would've been ideal. +1.

Comment: Ok, I've fleshed out a fuller `Aggregate` example.

Comment: I would set `count` to equal items.Count to start and then decrement it each step.  This means you are not evaluating the list count each time.  This means that if the function is passed a collection for which items.Count is expensive, the routine won't suffer

Comment: @BobVale - would I not still have to evaluate it every time to check when it reaches zero?

Comment: @BobVale - Sorry, misunderstood - I'm assuming you mean the items.Count part is expensive?

Comment: @DeeMac You would evaluate the `count` variable each time, but you wouldn't evaluate a potententially expensive `items.Count` with each iteration.

Comment: @BobVale: It's explicitly a `List<string>` in the question, but I agree in general. @DeeMac, he means initialize `int count = items.Count;`, then make the check `if (--count == 0)`.

Comment: @Porges Yes I agree, but a team member could create a new class that inherits from List<string> and pass it in with an overridden Count and then wonder why your code is so slow.....

Answer (score 1):

Use this (just one line code):

```
int i = 0;
string strResult = listOfStrings.Where(s => ++i != listOfStrings.Count)
                                .Aggregate("", (current, s) => current + s);
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
var count=listOfStrings.Count();

var result=listOfStrings.Aggregate(
   new { i=0, v=String.Empty},
   (x,y) => new { i=x.i+1, v=(x.i+1 == count) ? x.v + "&" + y : x.v+","+y},
   x=>x.v
   );
```